# how to change to c code while using for loop and array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, for-loop

I have created below code using c++ but unable to change it to c. I Try using c to have list of output shown at the end but unable to get the list. I need the c language code for below coding which is in c++. Please assist me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num;
    int state;
    int a,b,data[num];
    string element[2];

    cout<<"Enter amount data: ";
    cin>>num;
    for(a=0;a<num;a++){
        cout<<"Enter state: ";
        cin>>state;

        if(state==3){
            element[0]="A";
        } else if(state==10){
            element[1]="B";
        }   
    }
    cout<<"Elements are: ";
    for(b=0;b<num;b++){
        cout<<" "<<element[b];
    }
}
```

I tried using array but unable to get the list output

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int main(){
     int num;
     int state;
     int a,b,data[num];
     char str[];

     printf("Enter amount data: ");
     //cin>>num;
     scanf("%d",num);
     for(a=0;a<num;a++){
         printf("Enter state: ");
         //cin>>state;
         printf("%d",state);

         if(state==3){
             *str[0]="A";
         } else if(state==10){
             *str[1]="B";
         } 
     }
     printf("Elemets are: ");
     for(b=0;b<num;b++){
         puts(*str[b])
     }
}
```

Comment: "_using c++ but unable to change it to c_" - naah - but why? Isn't it perfect as is?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: Start by turning warning level of your compiler to a high level (e.g. gcc -Wall ...) and then fix all the warnings. BTW: Notice that the C++ version has bugs

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the C++ code because it contains a bug.

```
    string element[2];            // Array with 2 string

    cout<<"Enter amount data: ";
    cin>>num;                     // Read a number

    ...

    cout<<"Elements are: ";
    for(b=0;b<num;b++){           // Use the number as limit
        cout<<" "<<element[b];    // Print all string from 0 to number-1
    }
```

So if I give the program the input 42, the program will access `element[0]`, `element[1]`, `element[2]`, `element[3]`, ...., `element[41]` but the array **only has 2** elements so the program is accessing outside the array, i.e. the program has undefined behavior.

Converting an ill-formed C++ program to C seems pretty pointless but — of course — it can be converted into a likewise ill-formed C program.

So for the C program:

> Rule #1
>
> Set your compiler to **highest warning level** and **fix all warnings**

In C programming the warnings you get from the compiler is very often an indication of a bug. Therefore you must take warnings seriously and get them fixed. Don't even run your program if the compiler generates just a single warning. Make sure you have a clean compile (i.e. warning free compile) first.

Now compiling your program with "gcc -Wall" gives me:

```
main.cpp: In function 'main':
main.cpp:8:11: error: array size missing in 'str'
    8 |      char str[];
      |           ^~~
main.cpp:12:14: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   12 |      scanf("%d",num);
      |             ~^  ~~~
      |              |  |
      |              |  int
      |              int *
main.cpp:19:14: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
   19 |              *str[0]="A";
      |              ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:21:14: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
   21 |              *str[1]="B";
      |              ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:26:15: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
   26 |          puts(*str[b])
      |               ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:26:23: error: expected ';' before '}' token
   26 |          puts(*str[b])
      |                       ^
      |                       ;
   27 |      }
      |      ~                 
main.cpp:7:14: warning: unused variable 'data' [-Wunused-variable]
    7 |      int a,b,data[num];
      |              ^~~~
```

So you have 2 warnings (one of them is an actual error) but even worse, you also have 5 errors. All this tells you what to fix.

Your main issue is strings! The way you try to convert the C++ type `string` to C type string is wrong. So here is a little explanation of strings in C.

> There is no string type in C !

So

```
char str[];   // is NOT in any way compatible with C++ string element[2];
```

(It's actually an error in C.)

C strings are a special usage of a `char` array. The special usage is that one element in the char array must have the value `'\0'` (aka NUL). This element then signals END-OF-STRING.

So consider this:

```
char strA[2] = "A"; // strA[0] is 'A' and strA[1] is '\0'
```

In this way you have made a C string equal to "A". Notice: The string length is 1 but the array still needs two chars. That's because an extra char is needed for the `'\0'` to signal END-OF-STRING.

So if you want an array with two strings to hold either "A" or "B", you need to do:

```
 char str[2][2];  // instead of just char str[];
```

Further, you can't use `=` to assign values to strings in C. You need `strcpy` ("string copy"). Like:

```
strcpy(str[0], "A");  // instead of str[0] = "A"
```

Finally, to print the string with a newline after it, just use:

```
puts(str[0]);  // or puts(str[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

as string length will be decided after compiling it'll be set in run time by OS

```
 /* ...   */


    char str[]; 
    str = (char *) malloc(num+1);

  if(state==3){
    str[0]="A";
  } else if(state==10){
    str[1]="B";
  } 

/* ...    */
```

find yours

> if(state==3){

and try to put above in such